# How could I get file size, time and md5 from amazon s3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I wanna get a file's properties stored in amazon s3, is it easy to do that using api or php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for PHP is the AWS SDK for PHP - Google it.

Here are PHP examples of all of the properties you can receive:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html

some include getBucket, getObjectACL, list files, list buckets, etc

You can also use the command line awscli here:
http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for AWS PHP Ver 3

```
//Get file size
$s3 = new S3Client([
        'region' => REGION,
        'version' => '2006-03-01',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => AWS_KEY,
            'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        ],
]);

$result = $s3->getObject([
  'Bucket'  => BUCKET, 
    'Key'   => $files_name
]);
$files_size = $result['ContentLength'];
 echo "Size: " .  $files_size . "<br>";
```